# Can I have two group headers? Can I alternate printing them?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have 2 cases in my report. Depending on what values are coming from java I have to implement 2 different cases of printing data.

What is the easiest way to implement the structure of picture below? My idea was to make 2 groups (each group with a case from the picture below). I did this and I don't know how to show alteratively the groups. What about making a boolean parameter or something like this, checked in printWhenExpression?

The structure to implement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would put Case 1 and Case 2 in two separate bands, and apply the printWhenExpression onto the bands with a boolean expression.  For Case 1 you could either handle populating the data via a table or via subreport.  Hope this helps.